# JDO in GWT, what is PMF?

Tags: gwt, jdo

I try to learn use JDO in GWT from https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/creatinggettinganddeletingdata

In the first sample code, there is a line:

```
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
```

In this line, what is PMF? There is no answer in the tutorial, and I can not figured out.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with GWT at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PMF is a java class (Persistance Manager Factory)

You can find more information about it here : [Information PMF](http://db.apache.org/jdo/pmf.html)

You can find Source Code here : [PMF Source Code](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-examples/source/browse/trunk/DemoUpload/src/org/gonevertical/upload/server/PMF.java)